# NodeMCU server bad response, when sending GET request from Android app

Tags: android, lua, android-volley, okhttp, esp8266

I've made little server based on NodeMCU. All works good, when I'm conneting from browser, but problem starts, when I'm trying to connect from Android app uisng OkHttp or Volley, I'm receiving exceptions.
java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on Connection using OkHttp,
EOFException using Volley.

Problem is very similar for this
[EOFException after server responds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33396681/eofexception-after-server-responds), but answer didn't found.

**ESP server code**

```
srv:listen(80, function(conn)

  conn:on("receive", function(conn,payload)
    print(payload)
    conn:send("<h1> Hello, NodeMCU.</h1>")
  end)
  conn:on("sent", function(conn) conn:close() end)
end)
```

**Android code**

```
final RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
final String url = "http://10.42.0.17:80";
```

---

```
final StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    mTemperatureTextView.setText(response.substring(0, 20));
                    System.out.println(response);
                }
            },

            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    System.out.println("Error + " + error.toString());
                    mTemperatureTextView.setText("That didn't work!");
                }
            }
    );
```

---

```
mUpdateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            queue.add(request);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're sending back is not HTTP. It's nothing but a protocol-agnostic HTML fragment. Furthermore, there's a memory leak lingering.

Try this instead:

```
srv:listen(80, function(conn)

  conn:on("receive", function(sck,payload)
    print(payload)
    sck:send("HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\nServer: NodeMCU on ESP8266\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n<h1> Hello, NodeMCU.</h1>")
  end)
  conn:on("sent", function(sck) sck:close() end)
end)
```

- you need to send back some HTTP headers, `HTTP/1.0 200 OK` and the newlines are mandatory
- each function needs to use it's own copy of the passed socket instance, see how I renamed `conn` to `sck` in the two callback functions, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/37379426/131929 for details

For a more complete send example look at [`net.socket:send()` in the docs](http://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/dev/en/modules/net/#netsocketsend). That becomes relevant once you start sending more than just a couple of bytes.

Comment: Thank you very much, Marcel!

Comment: Thank you! I missed the headers part and that caused the issue.